# Number with non-constructive algebraicity proof

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is there a [computable number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) which is known to be algebraic but no explicit polynomial of which it is a root is known?

Comment: $\root{17}\of{42}+\root{53}\of{47}+\root{92}\of{87}$ is known to be algebraic, but I bet that as of this writing no one knows an explicit polynomial of which it is a root. Make it a little more complicated, and you could get a number for which it is not feasible to compute an explicit polynomial.

Comment: An algebraic number is always computable.